# Integral Schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $(X,\mathcal O)$ be a scheme. If $\mathcal O(U)$ is integral for all affine open $U\subset X$, how to show that $\mathcal O(V)$ is also integral for general open subset $V\subset X$?

Comment: I'm sure this has been already explained on here somewhere. The restriction map is injective--use this to reduce to affine case.